# error: error upgrading connection: error dialing backend: dial tcp <privateip>:10250: i/o timeout

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I created a AKS instance hosting an endpoint few months ago and it has been running fine and still is. 10-20 times previously, whenever I wanted to check something I have connected to the dashboard using the below command:

```
az aks browse --resource-group test-mytest-rg --name MyAKS
```

Today I tried to connect to the dashboard again but am now getting:

```
Merged "MyAKS" as current context in /var/folders/44/w_brzddd739bl8tb859j_wdc0000gn/T/tmpj4yuba33
Proxy running on http://127.0.0.1:8001/
Press CTRL+C to close the tunnel...
error: error upgrading connection: error dialing backend: dial tcp <privateip>:10250: i/o timeout
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8888): Max retries exceeded with url: /closeport/8001 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x110c306a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Users/martinblampied/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/martinblampied/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/martinblampied/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/martinblampied/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Users/martinblampied/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 166, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x110c306a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8888): Max retries exceeded with url: /closeport/8001 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x110c306a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 197, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 373, in execute
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    result = cmd(params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 182, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 440, in default_command_handler
    result = op(**command_args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py", line 1377, in aks_browse
    requests.post('http://localhost:8888/closeport/8001')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.50/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8888): Max retries exceeded with url: /closeport/8001 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x110c306a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

This is the first time I've tried to open the dashboard in around 3 weeks. Nothing has changed on my pod or kubernetes instance, it is still running successfully as expected. Potentially I have updated something on my mac which is causing the connection to be refused.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can check if the pod name `tunnelfront` is running.  If it isn't, force deletion of the pod and it will restart.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: @KarishmaTiwari-MSFT Didn't work for me. I ended up deleting the entire AKS instance and starting again.